# checking const char* as a non-type template argument

Tags: c++

using msvc 14, i would like to check a const char* argument as a non-type template argument.

```
template <typename T, const char Key[] = nullptr >
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}

    void f_not_null() {
        static_assert(Key != nullptr, "may be not null");
    }

    void f_null() {
        static_assert(Key == nullptr, "may be null");
    }
};

extern const char A_STRING[] = "a string";
Base<int, A_STRING> test;
test.f_not_null();

Base<int> test1;
test1.f_null();
```

The code below does not compile due to **error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant** on `static_assert(Key != nullptr, "may be not null")` when declaring 
`Base<int, A_STRING>`.

If possible I would not like to use a wrapper as a workaround:

```
template <const char *str>
class Str {
};

Base<int, Str<A_STRING> > test;
[...]
```

Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: If your variable is extern, why is it declared here?

Answer (score 1):

As Matthieu says, this will work if (and only if) you change:

```
extern const char A_STRING[] = "a string";
```

to:

```
static const char A_STRING[] = "a string";
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p8UpWpv47qNeWLKH)

Comment: Unfortunately, i m not using gcc, i use msvc 14 and this does not work and fall into `error C2971: 'Base': template parameter 'Key': 'A_STRING': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument` which is why i've used `extern`.

Comment: my code sample is a brief sample of a code using `extern` on a `const char*` declared into another compilation unit and is set to use a `static storage duration` with `external linkage`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, MSVC won't compile the code I posted, see: https://rextester.com/DUZQB23817.  I would call that an MSVC bug, since both gcc and clang are perfectly happy and the error message produced by MSVC makes no sense.  I think you are stuck here.